# how to use jquery mobile tapholdThreshold on listview items

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile application that has a listview on one of the pages. I would like to show a dialog when a user long clicks on a listview item. I was looking for examples but could not find any with the tapholdThreshold examples. If anyone could point me in the right direction or show a quick example that would be much appreciated. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps ...search for the taphold event..
http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-mobile-what-can-it-do-for-you/